# Vaadin MenuBar Acting Strangely with IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, vaadin, internet-explorer-11

Good evening everyone!

I have deployed an application made from Vaadin7 , and during testing, we encountered something weird when running the app on IE.

[image: Header on IE]

The menu bar shows only three(3) items and the rest is viewed via a triangular button. It only happens on IE (We have IE11 on the office btw, if it helps).. On firefox and chrome, it works perfectly, as shown in the picture below:

[image: Header Image on Chrome and firefox]

This is the code that I used for the header:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import no.solarsoft.studentweb.listener.MenuItemSelectionListener;
import no.solarsoft.studentweb.manager.ResourceManager;
import no.solarsoft.studentweb.manager.SessionHelper;
import no.solarsoft.studentweb.theme.StudentWebTheme;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import com.vaadin.server.FileResource;
import com.vaadin.server.Page;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinService;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Image;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class Header extends CustomComponent{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4573713330320823676L;
    List<MenuItemSelectionListener> menuItemListeners = new ArrayList<MenuItemSelectionListener>();
    private MenuBar barmenu ;
    private VerticalLayout headerLayout;
    private Panel panel;
    private Logger logger ;
    Image imgOrganisation;
    private MenuItem previous = null;
    private static final String BASE_PATH = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    public Header(){
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(Header.class);
        MenuBar.Command myCommand = new MenuBar.Command() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1224979160403018369L;

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = selectedItem.getId();

                for (MenuItemSelectionListener l : menuItemListeners) {
                    l.handleMenuItemSelection(id);

                }
                if(previous!=null){
                    previous.setStyleName(null);
                }
                selectedItem.setStyleName(StudentWebTheme.HEADER_HIGHLIGHT);
                previous = selectedItem;
            }
        };
            barmenu = new MenuBar();
            barmenu.addStyleName("mybarmenu");

            panel = new Panel();
            headerLayout = new VerticalLayout();
            imgOrganisation = ResourceManager.getInstance().getLogoAsImage(SessionHelper.getOrganisationCode()+".png");
            if(barmenu.getItems().size()==0){
                barmenu.addItem("PersonDetaljer", null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Studieplan", null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Studieprogrammer", null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Gjennomføringer", null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Eksamener",  null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Endelige Karakterer",  null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Lånekassen",  null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Artikkel",  null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Instillinger",  null,myCommand);
                barmenu.addItem("Logg av",  null,myCommand);
            }
            logger.info("menu bar size: {} ", barmenu.getItems().size());
            barmenu.setSizeFull();
            imgOrganisation .setSizeUndefined();
            barmenu.setVisible(false);
            headerLayout.addComponents(imgOrganisation,barmenu);
            headerLayout.setSpacing(true);
            panel.setContent(headerLayout);
            panel.setSizeUndefined();
            panel.setWidth("100%");
            panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
            setCompositionRoot(panel);
    }


    public void setMenuBarVisible(boolean visible){
        barmenu.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public void setMenuItemStyle(String uri){
        for(MenuItem item : barmenu.getItems()){
            logger.info(" \nitem: {} \nuri:{} \nprevious: {} ", item.getText(),
                    uri,previous==null?"null":previous.getText());
            if(uri.equalsIgnoreCase(itemToUri(item.getText()))){
                logger.info("bingo! ");
                item.setStyleName(StudentWebTheme.HEADER_HIGHLIGHT);
                previous=item;
            }else{
                item.setStyleName(null);
                logger.info("style name: {}", item.getStyleName());
                logger.info("null style");
            }
        }
    }

    public String itemToUri(String itemName){
        String newItemName="";
        for(int index =0;index<itemName.length();index++){
            switch(itemName.charAt(index)){
                case 'Å':
                case 'å':
                    newItemName+="aa";
                    break;
                case 'Ø':
                case 'ø':
                    newItemName+="oe";
                    break;
                case 'Æ':
                case 'æ':
                    newItemName+="ae";
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    break;
                default:
                    newItemName+=itemName.charAt(index);
            }
        }
        return newItemName;
    }

    public void addMenuItemSelectionListener(MenuItemSelectionListener l) {
        menuItemListeners.add(l);
    }
```

I wonder why it appears "weird" on IE. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Better if you ask on Vaadin forum. They will answer pretty fast from my experience.

Comment: Looks like IE has only a small "visible" area for your application. Vaadin does then render the "overflow" of the menu bar in a popup menu as you see it.

Comment: how do I increase the "visible area"? should I set my layout and panel to setSizeFull() or give it a defined width?  :/